# Answering machine in windows mobile with C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile

I want to develop an automatic answering machine in windows mobile with C#. It should auto-answer incoming calls and play an audio file.

Does anyone has any ideas? or may you know an existing app?

Comment: `existing app`? there are many. Do you want to develop the application your self or just looking for an answering machine? if yes then your question doesn't belong here, ask it on `superuser.com`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the phone, use the TAPI function [lineAnswer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918919).

To play a pre-recorded messasge:

1. Use the TAPI function [lineGetID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920556.aspx)( ..., "wave/out" ); to get a handle to the wav device associated with the phone hardware.
2. Use the ID received from step 1 with [waveInOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908147.aspx) to play a wav file to the telephone device.

To record calls:

1. Turn on [AllowInCallRecording](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599656.aspx)
2. Use the TAPI function [lineGetID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920556.aspx)( ..., "wave/out" ); to get a handle to the wav device associated with the phone hardware.
3. Use the ID received from step 2 with [waveOutOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910393.aspx) to pipe data from the telephone to a wav file.

For C#, you will need to P/Invoke these commands or see if they are provided by the [OpenNetCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/) framework.

-PaulH